# Google Chrome's strange behaviour on float numbers calculation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Just faced a strange behaviour in google chrome. It performs calculations incorrectly with float numbers. When I type in console `59.9 - 0.1` it gives `59.8`, but if I type `59.8 - 0.1` it gives `59.699999999999996`. Why does it happen and how to fix it? Version I am using is 45.0.2454.101 m.